# what is the best choice for push notification in flutter?

Tags: flutter

what is the best choice to use for push notification , since I want the notification for a specific user of the app. not all the user would see the same notification. I want also the notification to be sent even if the app closed and also deleted from the system tray.

is it to use:

1. google firebase.
2. one signal.
3. make a background service in flutter and use it to push notification.

thank you ...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at [Firebase Notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) using Google Cloud Messaging infrastructure.

Pros:

- Build on Google Infrastructure
- Fast, no credit card required
- Easy to integrate

Comment: does it have background notification?